# Get Data Matching from Other Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have three tables in the SQL server named **sold, details and customer**, my query is, in the sold table, I have a filed INV-NO which is a common field in the details table by name BILL-NO and in the details table I have a field CUSTID which is also in Customers Table.
 how to get CUSTID and Customer Name from Customer Table in the sold table matching with INV-NO from sold AND details table.

[image]

then CUSTID and Customer fields are blank in sold table I want to fill them from the other two tables. is it possible

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-inner-join/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it via inner join to retrieve customer name.

```
SELECT [C].[NAME] 
   FROM [SOLD] S
   JOIN [DETAILS] D ON [S].[INV-NO] = [D].[BILL-NO]
   JOIN [CUSTOMER] C ON [D].[CUSTID] = [C].[CUSTID]
```

If you want to update [SOLD] table with customer name then:

```
UPDATE S
   SET [S].[CUSTID] = [C].[CUSTID], [S].[CUSTOMER] = [C].[NAME]
FROM [SOLD] S
       JOIN [DETAILS] D ON [S].[INV-NO] = [D].[BILL-NO]
       JOIN [CUSTOMER] C ON [D].[CUSTID] = [C].[CUSTID]
```

It would be helpful if you have provided some sample data.

Based on comments, if you are trying on MS ACCESS then try the same query by replacing JOIN with INNER JOIN as below (for MS ACCESS ):

```
SELECT [C].[NAME] 
   FROM [SOLD] S
   INNER JOIN [DETAILS] D ON [S].[INV-NO] = [D].[BILL-NO]
   INNER JOIN [CUSTOMER] C ON [D].[CUSTID] = [C].[CUSTID]
```

If you are updating then the below query is for MS-ACCESS:

```
UPDATE S
   SET [S].[CUSTID] = [C].[CUSTID], [S].[CUSTOMER] = [C].[NAME]
FROM [SOLD] S
       INNER JOIN [DETAILS] D ON [S].[INV-NO] = [D].[BILL-NO]
       INNER JOIN [CUSTOMER] C ON [D].[CUSTID] = [C].[CUSTID]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am grateful to you. only one thing this query is not working on MS ACCESS but works fine on SQL server

Comment: You tagged the post under SQL Server. If you are trying on MS ACCESS, can you try the same query by replacing JOIN with INNER JOIN